# Swift equivalent @selector(allDistributedNotifications:)

Tags: notifications, swift, nsnotificationcenter

In Swift, what is the equivalent of `@selector(allDistributedNotifications:)` in string

`[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
      selector:@selector(allDistributedNotifications:)
      name:@"com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo"
      object:@"com.apple.iTunes.player"];`

I tried the following, but I get an error message

```
NSDistributedNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector(allDistributedNotifications), name: "com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo", object: "com.apple.iTunes.player")
```

Answer (score 2):

In swift the selector keys are just strings so it would be

```
NSDistributedNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "allDistributedNotifications:", name: "com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo", object: "com.apple.iTunes.player")
```

Comment: @gJamDev Also note I added back in the colon as well, which you didn't have in your swift attempt - which will send self as the first parameter to the `allDistributedNotifications` function

Comment: I rewrite this code and can't understand (in this part) how convert it into swift (full code)

`- (void)getter{
    [[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(allDistributedNotifications:)
            name:@"com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo"
          object:@"com.apple.iTunes.player"];
    
}

- (void) allDistributedNotifications:(NSNotification *)note {/*..*/}`

Comment: @gJamDev please ask a different question.. but search for duplicates first :D

Comment: selectors are not "just strings" -- they are `Selector`s -- it's just that `Selector` is `StringLiteralConvertible`, so you can use a string literal to specify it